Asyncio + Anthropic raises a "RuntimeError: Event loop is closed"
I have a very simple toy example that uses Anthropic and asyncio.
It is a loop that runs several times the asyncio.run() function.
Sometimes, a RuntimeError: Event loop is closed exception raised during the iterations and I don't understand why.
I guess I'm not using asyncio right, but I cannot understand where.
The code seems to run fine though.
import asyncio
from time import perf_counter

import numpy as np
from anthropic import Anthropic, AsyncAnthropic


async def coroutine1():
    prompt = "Who discovered gravity. Answer in 10 words."

    client = AsyncAnthropic()
    message = await client.messages.create(
        model="claude-3-5-sonnet-20240620",
        max_tokens=1024,
        messages=[{"role": "user", "content": prompt}],
    )

    return message.content[0].text


async def coroutine2():
    prompt = "Who discovered radioactivity. Answer in 10 words."

    client = AsyncAnthropic()
    message = await client.messages.create(
        model="claude-3-5-sonnet-20240620",
        max_tokens=1024,
        messages=[{"role": "user", "content": prompt}],
    )

    return message.content[0].text


async def main():
    async with asyncio.TaskGroup() as tg:
        t0 = tg.create_task(coroutine1())
        t1 = tg.create_task(coroutine2())
    print(t0.result())
    print(t1.result())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    for i in range(10):
        tic = perf_counter()
        asyncio.run(main())
        toc = perf_counter()
        print(f"Elapsed time = {toc - tic:.3f}")

Edit bellow. Here is the full traceback:
Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished name='Task-40' coro=<AsyncClient.aclose() done, defined at /Users/foo/Desktop/async/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/httpx/_client.py:2024> exception=RuntimeError('Event loop is closed')>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/foo/Desktop/async/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/httpx/_client.py", line 2031, in aclose
    await self._transport.aclose()
  File "/Users/foo/Desktop/async/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/httpx/_transports/default.py", line 389, in aclose
    await self._pool.aclose()
  File "/Users/foo/Desktop/async/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/httpcore/_async/connection_pool.py", line 313, in aclose
    await self._close_connections(closing_connections)
  File "/Users/foo/Desktop/async/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/httpcore/_async/connection_pool.py", line 305, in _close_connections
    await connection.aclose()
  File "/Users/foo/Desktop/async/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/httpcore/_async/connection.py", line 171, in aclose
    await self._connection.aclose()
  File "/Users/foo/Desktop/async/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/httpcore/_async/http11.py", line 265, in aclose
    await self._network_stream.aclose()
  File "/Users/foo/Desktop/async/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/httpcore/_backends/anyio.py", line 55, in aclose
    await self._stream.aclose()
  File "/Users/foo/Desktop/async/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/anyio/streams/tls.py", line 201, in aclose
    await self.transport_stream.aclose()
  File "/Users/foo/Desktop/async/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/anyio/_backends/_asyncio.py", line 1287, in aclose
    self._transport.close()
  File "/Users/foo/.pyenv/versions/3.12.1/lib/python3.12/asyncio/selector_events.py", line 1206, in close
    super().close()
  File "/Users/foo/.pyenv/versions/3.12.1/lib/python3.12/asyncio/selector_events.py", line 871, in close
    self._loop.call_soon(self._call_connection_lost, None)
  File "/Users/foo/.pyenv/versions/3.12.1/lib/python3.12/asyncio/base_events.py", line 792, in call_soon
    self._check_closed()
  File "/Users/foo/.pyenv/versions/3.12.1/lib/python3.12/asyncio/base_events.py", line 539, in _check_closed
    raise RuntimeError('Event loop is closed')
RuntimeError: Event loop is closed
Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished name='Task-41' coro=<AsyncClient.aclose() done, defined at /Users/foo/Desktop/async/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/httpx/_client.py:2024> exception=RuntimeError('Event loop is closed')>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/foo/Desktop/async/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/httpx/_client.py", line 2031, in aclose
    await self._transport.aclose()
  File "/Users/foo/Desktop/async/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/httpx/_transports/default.py", line 389, in aclose
    await self._pool.aclose()
  File "/Users/foo/Desktop/async/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/httpcore/_async/connection_pool.py", line 313, in aclose
    await self._close_connections(closing_connections)
  File "/Users/foo/Desktop/async/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/httpcore/_async/connection_pool.py", line 305, in _close_connections
    await connection.aclose()
  File "/Users/foo/Desktop/async/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/httpcore/_async/connection.py", line 171, in aclose
    await self._connection.aclose()
  File "/Users/foo/Desktop/async/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/httpcore/_async/http11.py", line 265, in aclose
    await self._network_stream.aclose()
  File "/Users/foo/Desktop/async/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/httpcore/_backends/anyio.py", line 55, in aclose
    await self._stream.aclose()
  File "/Users/foo/Desktop/async/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/anyio/streams/tls.py", line 201, in aclose
    await self.transport_stream.aclose()
  File "/Users/foo/Desktop/async/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/anyio/_backends/_asyncio.py", line 1287, in aclose
    self._transport.close()
  File "/Users/foo/.pyenv/versions/3.12.1/lib/python3.12/asyncio/selector_events.py", line 1206, in close
    super().close()
  File "/Users/foo/.pyenv/versions/3.12.1/lib/python3.12/asyncio/selector_events.py", line 871, in close
    self._loop.call_soon(self._call_connection_lost, None)
  File "/Users/foo/.pyenv/versions/3.12.1/lib/python3.12/asyncio/base_events.py", line 792, in call_soon
    self._check_closed()
  File "/Users/foo/.pyenv/versions/3.12.1/lib/python3.12/asyncio/base_events.py", line 539, in _check_closed
    raise RuntimeError('Event loop is closed')
RuntimeError: Event loop is closed


Could you share the full traceback of the RuntimeError?

I don't have an active Anthropic account to test, but two possible sources of the issue could be connection pooling (unrelated project but same type of RuntimeError); example: coroutine2 calling AsyncAnthropic() to make a new client might try to reuse the client created in coroutine1).  Another possibility is the OS event loop policy causing issues on Windows, switching to Selector policy may help.

@nigh_anxiety I edited the question and added the full traceback

@nigh_anxiety You might be right about the connection pooling. I tried one of the solutions described in your link and it seems to be working. I installed and used nest_asyncio: https://pypi.org/project/nest-asyncio/

The Anthropic client needs to be closed:
import asyncio
from time import perf_counter

import numpy as np
from anthropic import Anthropic, AsyncAnthropic


async def coroutine1():
    prompt = "Who discovered gravity. Answer in 10 words."

    client = AsyncAnthropic()
    message = await client.messages.create(
        model="claude-3-5-sonnet-20240620",
        max_tokens=1024,
        messages=[{"role": "user", "content": prompt}],
    )
    await client.close()

    return message.content[0].text


async def coroutine2():
    prompt = "Who discovered radioactivity. Answer in 10 words."

    client = AsyncAnthropic()
    message = await client.messages.create(
        model="claude-3-5-sonnet-20240620",
        max_tokens=1024,
        messages=[{"role": "user", "content": prompt}],
    )
    await client.close()

    return message.content[0].text


async def main():
    async with asyncio.TaskGroup() as tg:
        t0 = tg.create_task(coroutine1())
        t1 = tg.create_task(coroutine2())
    print(t0.result())
    print(t1.result())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    for i in range(10):
        tic = perf_counter()
        asyncio.run(main())
        toc = perf_counter()
        print(f"Elapsed time = {toc - tic:.3f}")


My opinion is that there is a library problem since this code is working well:
import asyncio
import aiohttp
from time import perf_counter

async def coroutine1():
    url = "https://www.google.com"
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get(url) as response:
            content = await response.text()
    return content[:100]  # return a snippet of the content for demonstration

async def coroutine2():
    url = "https://www.google.com"
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get(url) as response:
            content = await response.text()
    return content[:100]  # return a snippet of the content for demonstration

async def main():
    async with asyncio.TaskGroup() as tg:
        t0 = tg.create_task(coroutine1())
        t1 = tg.create_task(coroutine2())
    print(t0.result())
    print(t1.result())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    for i in range(10):
        tic = perf_counter()
        asyncio.run(main())
        toc = perf_counter()
        print(f"Elapsed time = {toc - tic:.3f}")


Do you mean there's a problem in the Anthropic library? Your code works fine on my computer. Were you able to reproduce the problem I mentioned?

I was not able to reproduce it, since I need some API keys from Anthropic.

Oh yes, sorry about that!
